# Spring MVC @RequestBody map Optional<Enum>

Tags: java, json, spring, enums, jackson

I have a rest controller with this method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = { RequestMethod.POST }, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity<?> add(@Valid @RequestBody MyModel myModel, Errors errors) {

        ...
        return new ResponseEntity<SomeObject>(someObject, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

In `MyModel` has a field `isMeetingOrSale` that is enum (`MeetingSaleFlag`):

```
public enum MeetingSaleFlag {
    MEETING("MEETING"),
    SALE("SALE");
    private final String name;       
    private MeetingSaleFlag(String s) { name = s; }
    public boolean equalsName(String otherName) {
       return (otherName == null) ? false : name.equals(otherName);
    }
    public String toString() { return this.name; }
}
```

and it can map a json that has a field `"isMeetingOrSale" : "MEETING"`

but the value in the json can be `"isMeetingOrSale" : ""` or completely missing, so in that case I want the field to be mapped to null. If I change the filed to be `Optional<MeetingSaleFlag>`

I got

> Could not read JSON: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type,
>   class `java.util.Optional<MeetingSaleFlag>`] from String value
>   ('MEETING'); no single-String constructor/factory method\\n at
>   [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@32b21158; line: 17, column: 18]
>   (through reference chain: MyModel[\"isMeetingOrSale\"]);

So the question is how can I map Optional enum from json?

Comment: I don't know the exact expected JSON for mapping to an `Optional`, but take a look at jackson module support for [`java.util.Optional`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jdk8). You'll have register a custom `ObjectMapper` in your configuration for the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`.

Comment: Spring framework supports Converters and Formatters. We used one of those for the underlying JPA layer. It should also work for JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Sotirios Delimanolis's comment I was able to resolve the issue.

### 1) Add

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

as a dependency.

### 2) Reconfigure the Jackson mapper. Register:

```
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
        return mapper;
    }
```

**OR** do this to register the jdk8 module

```
/**
 * @return Jackson jdk8 module to be registered with every bean of type
 *         {@link ObjectMapper}
 */
@Bean
public Module jdk8JacksonModule() {
    return new Jdk8Module();
}
```

> Another way to customize Jackson is to add beans of type com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module to your context. They will be registered with every bean of type ObjectMapper, providing a global mechanism for contributing custom modules when you add new features to your application.

Doing this will only register the additional module and keep the built-in Jackson configuration provided by Spring Boot.

### 3) result

Now when the property is missing from the sent json, it's mapped to null
**(This is not that great. I was expecting that it will give me an Optional and I will be able to use `.isPresent()`)**.
When it's an empty string (`"isMeetingOrSale" : ""`), Jackson returns an error:

> Could not read JSON: Can not construct instance of
>   MyModel from String value '': value not
>   one of declared Enum instance names: [VAL1, VAL2]

which looks OK to me.

Useful links : [Jackson jdk8 module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jdk8), [Spring MVC configure Jackson](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper)

Answer (score 3):

This is an example from our codebase:

```
@NotNull // You probably don't want this
@JsonSerialize(using=CountrySerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using=CountryDeserializer.class)
private CountryCode country;
```

where CountryCode is a *complex* enum (see [nv-i18n](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-i18n)) and these are the classes to (de)serialized from/to JSON:

```
public class CountrySerializer extends JsonSerializer<CountryCode> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(CountryCode value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeString(value.getAlpha3()); // Takes the Alpha3 code
    }

    public Class<CountryCode> handledType() { return CountryCode.class; }
}
```

and

```
public class CountryDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<CountryCode> {
    @Override
    public CountryCode deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        // You can add here the check whether the field is empty/null
        return CountryCode.getByCode(jp.getText());
    }
}
```

You can easily replicate the same scenario using **MeetingSaleFlag** instead of **CountryCode**.